# PHP cURL How can i select radio button value and submit without clicking on button

Tags: php, curl

How can I select "SUBMIT TO FACEBOOK FOR REVIEW" value and then "SUBMIT" without clicking buttons using `php cURL`

Here's the URL:

```
https://mbasic.facebook.com/nfx/basic/question/?context_str=%7B%22type%22%3A%222%22%2C%22initial_action_name%22%3A%22REPORT_CONTENT%22%2C%22story_location%22%3A%22page%22%2C%22entry_point%22%3A%22unknown%22%2C%22breadcrumbs%22%3A%5B%22offensive%22%2C%22hatespeech%22%2C%22religious%22%5D%2C%22reportable_ent_token%22%3A%22645850285587588%22%7D&redirect_uri=%2Fweirdgeometry&prev_action_info=%7B%22action_name%22%3A%22REPORT_CONTENT%22%2C%22completed_title%22%3A%22Submitted+to+Facebook+for+Review%22%2C%22completed_subtitle%22%3A%22You+have+submitted+a+report.%22%7D#_=_
```

Here's the source code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <meta name="referrer" content="default" id="meta_referrer" />
    <style type="text/css">
      /*<![CDATA[*/

      .c .k {
        border: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .c .k tbody {
        vertical-align: top;
      }

      .c .ba>tr>td,
      .c .ba>tbody>tr>td,
      .c .k td.ba {
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .c .k td {
        padding: 0;
      }

      .c .k td.z {
        padding: 4px;
      }

      .c .k td.m {
        padding: 6px;
      }

      .c .l {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .n {
        background-color: #3b5998;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .be {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 6px 0 6px 6px;
      }

      ._ li:not(:last-child) {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      }

      .c .z {
        padding: 4px;
      }

      .c .m {
        padding: 6px;
      }

      .o {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
      }

      .bg {
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      form {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
      }

      .r {
        border-color: #ccced3 #c4c6ca #b4b6ba;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
      }

      .q>*,
      .q.q>* {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      }

      .q>:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      .q+.q {
        border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      }

      .p {
        background: #fff;
      }

      .j {
        background: #e9ebee;
      }

      .h {
        background-color: #fff;
      }

      .s {
        background-color: #fffbe2;
        color: #7f7212;
      }

      .t {
        padding: 2px 3px;
      }

      .u {
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
      }

      .h {
        border-color: #e9e9e9;
      }

      .s {
        border-color: #e2c822;
      }

      .bd {
        color: #000;
      }

      .v {
        color: gray;
      }

      body,
      tr,
      input,
      textarea,
      .i {
        font-size: medium;
      }

      .w {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        min-width: inherit;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .y {
        display: block;
      }

      .bh {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        background: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 12px;
        height: 28px;
        line-height: 28px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0 9px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      .c .bh {
        border-radius: 2px;
      }

      .bk,
      a.bk,
      .c a.bk,
      .c a.bk:visited {
        background-color: #f5f6f7;
        color: #4b4f56;
      }

      .c a.bk:hover,
      .c .bk:hover {
        background-color: #ebedf0;
        color: #4b4f56;
      }

      .c .bk {
        border: 1px solid #bec3c9;
      }

      .bk[disabled] {
        color: #bec3c9;
      }

      .c .bk[disabled]:hover {
        background-color: #f5f6f7;
        color: #bec3c9;
      }

      .bj,
      a.bj,
      html .c a.bj {
        color: #fff;
      }

      .c .bj {
        background-color: #4267b2;
        border: 1px solid #365899;
      }

      .c a.bj:hover,
      .c .bj:hover {
        background-color: #465e91;
      }

      .bj[disabled] {
        color: #899bc1;
      }

      .c .bj[disabled]:hover {
        background-color: #4267b2;
      }

      .bi {
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 36px;
        line-height: 36px;
        padding: 0 16px;
      }

      .c a.bh::after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .c .bh {
        padding: 0 8px;
      }

      .c a.bh {
        height: 26px;
        line-height: 26px;
      }

      .c .bi {
        padding: 0 15px;
      }

      .c a.bi {
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 34px;
        line-height: 34px;
      }

      .c a,
      .c a:visited {
        color: #3b5998;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .c a:focus,
      .c a:hover {
        background-color: #3b5998;
        color: #fff;
      }

      body {
        text-align: left;
        direction: ltr;
      }

      body,
      tr,
      input,
      textarea,
      button {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      body,
      p,
      figure,
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      ul,
      ol,
      li,
      dl,
      dd,
      dt {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6 {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      ul,
      ol {
        list-style: none;
      }

      article,
      aside,
      figcaption,
      figure,
      footer,
      header,
      nav,
      section {
        display: block;
      }

      .f #viewport {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 600px;
      }

      #page {
        position: relative;
      }

      /*]]>*/

    </style>
  </head>

  <body tabindex="0" class="b c d e f g h">
    <div class="i">
      <div id="viewport">
        <div id="objects_container">
          <div class="j" id="root" role="main">
            <table class="k" role="presentation">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="l">
                    <div class="m n"><span class="o">Report</span></div>
                    <form method="post" action="/nfx/basic/handle_action/?context_str=%7B%22type%22%3A%222%22%2C%22initial_action_name%22%3A%22REPORT_CONTENT%22%2C%22story_location%22%3A%22page%22%2C%22entry_point%22%3A%22unknown%22%2C%22breadcrumbs%22%3A%5B%22offensive%22%2C%22hatespeech%22%2C%22religious%22%5D%2C%22additional_data%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22reportable_ent_token%22%3A%22645850285587588%22%7D&amp;is_direct=0&amp;redirect_uri=%2Fweirdgeometry&amp;prev_action_info=%7B%22action_name%22%3A%22REPORT_CONTENT%22%2C%22completed_title%22%3A%22Submitted+to+Facebook+for+Review%22%2C%22completed_subtitle%22%3A%22You+have+submitted+a+report.%22%7D&"
                      id="actions-form"><input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQGWXiUi42rn:AQE8P18qBIuU" autocomplete="off" /><input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="265817187881058510552501141105865816956804956113667311785" autocomplete="off" />
                      <div class="p q r">
                        <div>
                          <div class="s t u"><span class="i">Submitted to Facebook for Review</span><br /><span class="v">You have submitted a report.</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset class="w q"><label class="x y"><div class="z"><table class="k ba" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="bb" style="align-self:flex-start; margin-top: 20px;" id="m_check_list_aria_label"><input aria-labelledby="m_check_list_aria_label" class="bc" type="radio" name="action_key" value="REPORT_CONTENT" /></td><td class="l"><div class="z"><div><span class="bd">Submit to Facebook for Review</span><div><span class="v">Report this Page if it violates our <a target="_blank" href="/communitystandards">Community Standards</a>.</span></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></label>
                          <label
                            class="x y">
                            <div class="z">
                              <table class="k ba" role="presentation">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="bb" style="align-self:flex-start; margin-top: 20px;" id="m_check_list_aria_label"><input aria-labelledby="m_check_list_aria_label" class="bc" type="radio" name="action_key" value="BLOCK_PAGE" /></td>
                                    <td class="l">
                                      <div class="z">
                                        <div><span class="bd">Block Weird Geometry</span>
                                          <div><span class="v">You won&#039;t be able to see or contact each other.</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </div>
                            </label><label class="x y"><div class="z"><table class="k ba" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="bb" style="align-self:flex-start; margin-top: 20px;" id="m_check_list_aria_label"><input aria-labelledby="m_check_list_aria_label" class="bc" type="radio" name="action_key" value="UNSUBSCRIBE" /></td><td class="l"><div class="z"><div><span class="bd">Hide all from Weird Geometry</span><div><span class="v">Stop seeing posts from this Page</span></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></label></fieldset>
                      </div>
                      <div class="be"><input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="bf bg bh bi bj" /></div>
                      <div class="be"><input value="Done" type="submit" name="done" class="bf bg bh bi bk" /></div>
                    </form>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLH1a.jpg)

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: Add classname to the radio buttons and then use the click event to get the value which radio button is clicked. So using AJAX you can call your PHP CURL function.

Comment: any other simple way?